# Firefox (still) doesn`t print divs positioned absolutely?

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I've read about postion:absolute problems and tried almost every possible solution. Including positioning divs relatively, wrapping them in a relatively positioned parent etc etc, but it didn`t help.

I'm drawing a table and after that im putting divs in it in a specified place. Table (grid) prints fine but places where divs should be are printed in slightly different color and  divs aren`t there. In chrome it prints ok. Has anyone managed to find a solution yet? Maybe I'm doing something else wrong?

My css:

```
body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: Verdana;
-moz-user-select: none;
}
.grid
{
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.grid tr
{
text-align:center;
border-bottom: 1px dashed;
cursor: cursor;
}
.grid td.hourCell
{
width: 100px;
vertical-align:top;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: 500;
height: 60px;
}
.grid th.hourCell
{
width: 100px;
}
.grid th
{
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
width: 200px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 500;
font-family: Verdana;
border-right: 1px solid;
background-repeat: repeat;
cursor: cursor;
}
.grid td
{
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
vertical-align: top;
}
.div_which_doesnt_print
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 200px;
font-size: 10px;
font-family: Verdana;
height: 0px;
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
overflow: hidden;
opacity:0.7;
z-index: 3;
}
```

Every help would be greatly appreciated! Even reassuring me that solution is still unavaible.

**EDIT:** It looks like it was an issue with opacity. Setting

```
@media print 
{
.div_which_doesnt_print
{
opacity:1;
}
}
```

Fixed the issue with visibility. They still display sometimes in wrong places, but that`s a different issue.

Comment: Are you making a table out of divs? Why not just use a table?

Comment: I think that combination of `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` is making trouble, why you want it that way? Try to explain what div should look like...

Comment: No, I`m making a table (class "grid"). And over taht table I'm positioning divs in specific places. It should look similiar to a calendar (f.e. google calendar). Table is the whole day/time grid and the divs are events in that calendar.

Comment: P.S. Removing either height, overflow or both doesn't help.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo page with the full HTML so we can test ourselves?

Comment: Not really unfortunately. It`s only a small part of a bit project and it has a lot dependencies from local server to display anything :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue with opacity. Setting

```
@media print 
{
  .div_which_doesnt_print
  {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

Fixed the issue with visibility. They still display sometimes in wrong places, but that`s a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Inserting the Divisions Inside the Table Cells, then just give the Cell TD/TR position to relative and then give absolute positioning to the div inside it.

This was working fine for me in few projects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is not that simple, I`m inserting the divs **over** a few cells, not inside one :/ So their only parent is body. Wrapping them in a mock div with position: relative didn`t work either :/

Comment: can you post the html content?

Comment: It was problem with opacity. It's a bit weird that chrome could handle that, so I didn't think about it earlier.

Comment: for proper functioning of opacity, you must add a doctype declaration for your page

Comment: I have doctype xhmtl transitional. It displays ok, but it doesn't print when set to less than 1.